# annotation_logticks with log1p transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Is there a to way to adjust `annotation_logticks()` in `ggplot2` to work with `log1p` transformation?

Example:

```
library("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), outcome = c(5, 10, 30))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome)) + geom_col()
```

This produces the desired results:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log") +
  annotation_logticks(base = exp(1), sides = "l")
```

[image]

This does not (notice the two sets of ticks do not line up):

```
p + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log1p") +
  annotation_logticks(base = exp(1), sides = "l")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `breaks` within `scale_y_continuous`:

```
p  + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log1p", breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 20))
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but I was hoping to have them be generated automatically.